# Look for inside-out introduction of TCL for C programmer

Tags: tcl

I am taking a project to add TCL interface to our C based software. There are some tutorials on the web how to extend TCL commands and I did some before, but this project is more involving, I need to come up new Tcl_Object, Tcl_Type, etc. and manipulate interpreter in some certain way. So what are the relationship between those internal TCL data structures is important.

I googled "TCL inside-out for C programmer", as expected, nothing meaningful comes up. It seems to me I will need to check out TCL source code, before I do that, if you are aware of something on the web or bookstore, please share.

Comment: The two books listed in the answers below, the Ousterhout 2nd ed. and the Welch 4th ed., are considered to be _the_ key references for Tcl at the time of this question, including for interfacing Tcl to C. I have both. (Admittedly, I wrote a fair chunk of one of them so I'm not unbiased…)

Answer (score 3):

I like the "Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk" book by Brent B Welch, Ken Jones, and Jeffrey Hobbs (ISBN: 0130385603). They have nearly 100 pages out of ~850 devoted to C programming and Tcl. As far as I know, this is the most extensive source of C programming for Tcl. Check out bookhq.com for best price.

Answer (score 3):

The second edition of
Tcl and the Tk Toolkit (Addison-Wesley Professional Computing) von Ken Jones und John K. Ousterhout from 2009 is covering  also the C-side of Tcl extensively in 18 chapters.